# How pass dynamic values to ProgressBar and below message based number forms completed?

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying progress bar, progress bar status message bellow by passing static values, how can pass dynamic values to progress bar and bellow progress bar i need show progress bar status message dynamically. bellow I written code for static. please help me for passing dynamic values to progress bar, and progress bar status message.

```
html
----
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">

    <div>   
        <form ng-hide="form_1" name="form1" novalidate>
            <span>
                <input name="group1" type="radio" value="Yes" ng-model ="user.ans1" ng-required="true" />Yes
                <input name="group1" type="radio" value="NO" ng-model ="user.ans1" ng-required="true" />No
            </span><br/>
            <span>
                <input name="group2" type="radio" value="Yes" ng-model ="user.ans2" ng-required="true" />Yes
                <input name="group2" type="radio" value="NO" ng-model ="user.ans2" ng-required="true" />No
            </span><br/>
            <span>
                <button type="button" ng-disabled="form1.$invalid" ng-click="start();">start</button>
            </span>
        </form>

        <form ng-show="form_2" name="form2" novalidate>
        <div>
            <p progressbar prog="form2.$valid ? '33':'0'" ></p>
            <p>{{form2.$valid ? 'Set 1 of 3 completed':''}}</p>
        </div>
            <span>
               <input name="group3" type="radio" value="Male" ng-model ="gender" ng-required="true" /> Male
               <input name="group3" type="radio" value="Female" ng-model ="gender" ng-required="true" /> Female
           </span><br/>
            <button type="button"  ng-disabled="form2.$invalid" ng-click="form2Next();" >Next</button>
        </form>
        <form ng-show="form_3" name="form3" novalidate>
            <div>
                <p progressbar prog="form3.$valid ? '66':'33'" ></p>
                <p>{{form3.$valid ? 'Set 1 of 3 completed':''}}</p>
            </div>
            <span>
               <input name="group4" type="radio" value="btech" ng-model ="course" ng-required="true" /> Btech
               <input name="group4" type="radio" value="mtech" ng-model ="course" ng-required="true" /> Mtech
           </span><br/>
            <button type="button"  ng-disabled="form3.$invalid" ng-click="form3Next();" >Next</button>
        </form> 
        <form ng-show="form_4" name="form4" novalidate>
            <div>
                <p progressbar prog="form4.$valid ? '100':'66'" ></p>
                <p>{{form4.$valid ? 'Set 1 of 3 completed':''}}</p>
            </div>
            <span>
               <input name="group5" type="radio" value="software" ng-model ="emp" ng-required="true" /> software
               <input name="group5" type="radio" value="hardware" ng-model ="emp" ng-required="true" /> hordeware
           </span><br/>
            <button type="button"  ng-disabled="form4.$invalid" ng-click="form4Next();" >Next</button>
        </form>         
    </div>
</div>

script
------
        angular.module("app", [])
        .controller("main", ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.start = function(){
            if((($scope.user.ans1 == "Yes")&&($scope.user.ans2 == "Yes"))||(($scope.user.ans1 == "No")&&($scope.user.ans2 == "Yes"))){
                $scope.form1Next();
            }
            else{
                $scope.form2Next();
            }
        }// startasignment function End
        $scope.form1Next = function(){debugger;
            $scope.form_1 = true;
            $scope.form_2 = true;
        }
        $scope.form2Next = function(){debugger;
            $scope.form_1 = true;
            $scope.form_2 = false;
            $scope.form_3 = true;

        }
        $scope.form3Next = function(){debugger;
            $scope.form_2 = false;
            $scope.form_3 = false;
            $scope.form_4 = true;
        }
        $scope.form4Next = function(){debugger;
            alert("successfully submited")
            $scope.form_4 = false;
        }

        }])
        .directive('progressbar', [function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    'progress': '=prog'
                },
                template: '<div class="stripe" style="background-color: #C7D2D2; height:30px; width:100%;"> <div  ng-style="style" style="background-color:#FFFF00; height:100%"></div> </div>',
                controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {       
                 $scope.$watch(function() {
                        $scope.style = {"width": $scope.progress + "%"}
                    })
                }
            }
        }]);
```

Comment: please help me any one i update code in jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/8Yz7S/357/

Answer (score 0):

if you'r using an angularjs progress bar directive

then you can assign a variable to the prog attribute and manipulate it as you want like

```
<p progressbar prog="Progress" ></p>
```

call it like :

```
<input type="button" value="add 10" ng-click="AddProgress(10)">
```

and in controller

```
$scope.Progress ='0';

 $scope.AddProgress = function (percentige) {
 $scope.Progress = parseInt($scope.Progress)+percentige; 
 }
```

now you can put the `progressbar` in a shared div (without hiding and showing) and maybe animate it ..

first thing i found when searched angularJs progress bar was [this cool looking thing](http://www.bootply.com/VniecFIfQs)

here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/modar/tbxm3Lrd/2/)

Comment: I tried but it is working , can you show me in demo , how it work your code

Comment: Can you add the directive your using or its library ,, for me i used the one suggested in the answer

Comment: i am not using library, i  writen static code for progress bar it working but now i am doing dynamic but it not coming , i tryed your code but it not working , please help me

Comment: turns out that problem with javascript not parsing to Int

Comment: I update my code in jsfiddle , can you show me in jsfiddle, please

Comment: your also passing static values, base forms count we need form pass value, if user select yes , yes , start form form2 next form 3 and next form 4, if you select yes no then start form3 next form4 , based on user input we need pass value to progress bar , how i can please help me

Comment: i'm putting static value for demonstration purposes you can set the variable `Porgress` wherever you need and assing whichever value to it and it will get the progress bar to update ,, the function `AddProgress(value)` was for demonstration purposes

Comment: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/modar/tbxm3Lrd/2/) is a progress bar which gets its value from a text input ,, morever where are you expecting to get the dynamic value from ?

Comment: if user select option 'yes', 'yes', clicked start button then form2 will show, progrss bellow message will like 'Set 1 of 3 completed' because form2 next form 3 next form 4. if user select 'yes' , 'no' option then form 3 will show progress bar bellow message i need like 'Set 1 of 2 completed' because only 2 forms is pending to show(form3 and form4).

Comment: when i clicked start button , how can i pass number forms hide to progress bar

Comment: i don`t know how is it possible to get the number of hidden forms or at your case which are left in the flow anyway best of luck , [here](http://jsfiddle.net/modar/8Yz7S/355/) are some of my attempts that may help out

Comment: each form as 'one set' total 3 form's then 3 sets, based user select we will calculate the now forms  if you select 'yes' , 'yes' total sets is 3 or if you user select 'yes' , 'no' option then total sets ' 2', if user select second category like 'yes', 'no' option then 'totla set is 2' , when he clicked next button one form is set is completed  message show like this  'Set 4 of 3 completed'

Comment: how to make total sets dynamicaly based user input, i update js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8Yz7S/354/